# Control results of clicking on expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need to implement expandable list view to my application. 
This list will be used to add some ingredients to pizza, so I need to increase the prize when the ingredient is checked and decrease when ingredient is unchecked.

I find the code for custom expandable list and modify to match to my needs.

thats the code for adapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {



        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<customPizzaSendInfo>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<customPizzaSendInfo>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final customPizzaSendInfo childText = (customPizzaSendInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expander_list_item, null);
            }

            CheckBox txtListChild = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText.nameString);
            txtListChild.setChecked(childText.choosen);
            txtListChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {             


                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked == true)
                    {

                        prizeSmall += childText.priceSmallDouble;
                        prizeBig += childText.priceBigDouble;
                        normalnaButton.setText("Normalna " +String.valueOf(prizeSmall));
                        duzaButton.setText("Duża " + String.valueOf(prizeBig));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(childText.priceSmallDouble), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else
                    {
                        prizeSmall -= childText.priceSmallDouble;
                        prizeBig -= childText.priceBigDouble;
                        normalnaButton.setText("Normalna " +String.valueOf(prizeSmall));
                        duzaButton.setText("Duża " + String.valueOf(prizeBig));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }



        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expander_list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }


    }
```

this is the code for class which contain data `customPizzaSendInfo`

```
public class customPizzaSendInfo {

    public String nameString;
    public boolean choosen;
    public Double priceSmallDouble;
    public Double priceBigDouble;
    public customPizzaSendInfo(String nameString, boolean choosen, Double priceSmallDouble, Double priceBigDouble) {
        super();
        this.nameString = nameString;
        this.choosen = choosen;
        this.priceSmallDouble =  priceSmallDouble;
        this.priceBigDouble = priceBigDouble;
    }


}
```

there are two problems:

- how update the _listDataChild, cause when I close expander and then open it back I get the result like it was putted in,
- when I scrool the list, my price increases, so the android interpreting my touch to scroll like I was checking object, but the checkbox doesn't change state,

If i try to make on any click litener to monitoring the state of children, I got no reaction, so I decide to make it inside AdapterClass.

How to solve it

UPDATE I try to update this _listDataChild which keeps data about objects, so I modify the on checkChanged

```
@Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked == true)
                    {
                        //
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(childPosition) + " " + childText.nameString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), _listDataChild.get("Skonfiguruj Dodatki").get(childPosition).nameString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        _listDataChild.get("Skonfiguruj Dodatki").get(childPosition).choosen = true;
                        prizeSmall += childText.priceSmallDouble;
                        prizeBig += childText.priceBigDouble;
                        normalnaButton.setText("Normalna " +String.valueOf(prizeSmall));
                        duzaButton.setText("Duża " + String.valueOf(prizeBig));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(childText.priceSmallDouble), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else
                    {
                        _listDataChild.get("Skonfiguruj Dodatki").get(childPosition).choosen = false;
                        prizeSmall -= childText.priceSmallDouble;
                        prizeBig -= childText.priceBigDouble;
                        normalnaButton.setText("Normalna " +String.valueOf(prizeSmall));
                        duzaButton.setText("Duża " + String.valueOf(prizeBig));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            });
```

When i scroll the object become unchecked ...

SOLUTION
How I solve it by add onclick listener in the ExpandableListAdapter and I use advice of @Abd El-Rahman El-Tamawy to update _listDataChild and it works like a charm, here is the code.

```
txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 if(_listDataChild.get("Skonfiguruj Dodatki").get(childPosition).choosen)
                 {
                     _listDataChild.get("Skonfiguruj Dodatki").get(childPosition).choosen = false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     _listDataChild.get("Skonfiguruj Dodatki").get(childPosition).choosen = true;
                 }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should save the state of the button in your `HashMap` also in your `onClickListener` to enable your `adapter` to redraw the final state from the `HashMap` when you `collapse` and `expand` the parent again as following

```
@Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked == true)
                {
                    childText.
                    prizeSmall += childText.priceSmallDouble;
                    prizeBig += childText.priceBigDouble;
                    normalnaButton.setText("Normalna " +String.valueOf(prizeSmall));
                    duzaButton.setText("Duża " + String.valueOf(prizeBig));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(childText.priceSmallDouble), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else
                {
                    prizeSmall -= childText.priceSmallDouble;
                    prizeBig -= childText.priceBigDouble;
                    normalnaButton.setText("Normalna " +String.valueOf(prizeSmall));
                    duzaButton.setText("Duża " + String.valueOf(prizeBig));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //Get the HashMap Item of the current position and set all its value with the new values
                 this._listDataChild.get("yourCurrentKey").get(position).choosen = !this._listDataChild.get("yourCurrentKey").get(position)..choosen;
                 //Complete saving all your data
```

Comment: yeah, I try this modification I add this in update to make it clear, but It still doesn't work as I wish

Comment: Check the updated answer and follow the way of saving your data in ` this._listDataChild`

Comment: The same when I scroll the expander, checkbox became unchecked if they go out of bound of expander

Comment: When I try to add this. i get " this. _listDataChild cannot be resolved or is not a field:" :/

Comment: Actually, this is the Trick "Save every change you made in the Global `HashMap` because redrawing the list again will be from it" Try to do it correctly and your problem will be solved :)

Comment: I mark your question cause you give me advice which force me to solution and I put how to solve it in update, thx a lot